# Multiple magento-2 modules in single git repository

Tags: magento2, module, composer, git, bitbucket

I am trying to host my magento 2 extensions in a bitbucket repository.
each extension will be a branch of that repository. The problem is that, we need to create tag for particular version of the extension as the composer takes tag as version in `composer require vendor/module:<version>`, and the tags can not be duplicated, so if there are two extensions with same version, it will not work. There needs to be single repository to avoid adding new repository to composer to install a new extension every time.

And we need to have version to be `comparable` as the magento composer.json has `minimum-stability` defined as `alpha`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont't think that what you try tot do is possible within a single repository. A beter solution would be to setup your own repository with a tool like Satis or Toran Proxy (https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md). Here you can add multiple source repositories (one for every extension) and you can limit the access to the packages with authentication. Then you only need to add that repository to your installation and you have easy access to the packages.